# VBA to Copy Data from Another Workbook in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Problem: 
A problem in making a cell reference in VBA for source workbook name. Error 9 subscripts out of range.

Task I am doing?
Ex. I have to copy 32 columns out of 50 columns from a workbook(Master) into a new workbook. I am able to make a code to copy and paste the column in the required sequence in new workbook.

The master workbook is a template of a register to take peoples information and it saved with a new name. 
I have more than 65 workbooks(Master) to copy. I was trying to make a cell reference where I paste the source workbook(Master) name. I am aware that source workbook has to be open will running VBA.

I made icell as variable to fetch that value from cell B2, where I pasted workbook name but code is not running.

Code attached
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
    Dim iCell As String  
    iCell = Workbooks("Crack it").Worksheets("Intro").Range("B2").Value
    'B2 will store the name of source workbook for copying data which will keep on changing 

    Workbooks("iCell").Worksheets("Register").Range("E2:E50").Copy
    Workbooks("Crack it.xlsm").Worksheets("Risk").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'Refid

    Workbooks("iCell").Worksheets("Register").Range("H2:H50").Copy
    Workbooks("Crack it.xlsm").Worksheets("Risk").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'Tags

    Workbooks("iCell").Worksheets("Register").Range("A2:A50").Copy
    Workbooks("Crack it.xlsm").Worksheets("Risk").Range("c2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'Name

    Workbooks("iCell").Worksheets("Register").Range("Z2:Z50").Copy
    Workbooks("Crack it.xlsm").Worksheets("Risk").Range("D2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'Element

    ...... code keeps on repeating till column 32th 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ahve somethign similar, I read all the files located on a folder for your case you will save all the 65 Workbooks in a folder, then read each one of them with a loop, once it takes the first book opened you will take the info:

```
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1) & sItem + "\"
    FilePathBox.Value = sItem
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem & "\"
Set fldr = Nothing
```

If you see my code above it taks the url of the folder, then I will start a process that will see file by file:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    UserForm1.Top = (Application.Height / 2) - (UserForm1.Height / 2) + 45
    UserForm1.Left = (Application.Width / 2) - (UserForm1.Width / 2) + 200
    UserForm1.Label1.Visible = True
    Label1.Caption = ""
    '-----------------------------------------THIS IS THE LOOP OFR EACH FILE INTO THE FOLDER--------------------------------------------------
    MyPath = UserForm2.FilePathBox.Value
    Dim strFilename As String
    strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "*.txt", vbNormal)
    filesc = 1
    If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Do Until strFilename = ""
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        If filesc >= 1 Then
            showBarName.Caption = showBarName.Caption & strFilename
            'Worksheets.Add(Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Data"
            Call ThisWorkbook.XY_Data((UserForm2.FilePathBox.Value & strFilename), (strFilename & ""))
            showBarName.Caption = "Generating XY Data for %PATH%/"
        End If
        filesc = filesc + 1
        counter = counter + cols
        strFilename = Dir()
    Loop
    '------------------------------------------END--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Worksheets("Spec").Visible = True
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
         If ws.Name = "Spec" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next ws
    UserForm1.Hide
    showBarName.Caption = "Saving File"
    'THIS IS FOR XLSX
    Application.StatusBar = "Save your file into the PNL Project path."
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim hoja As Worksheet
    For Each hoja In Sheets
        If ActiveSheet.Name = "Data" Then
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
        End If
    Next hoja
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    fileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    If fileSaveName <> False Then
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:=51
    End If
    showBarName.Caption = "Generating XY Data for %PATH%/"
    'This is to close the macro without saving
    Application.StatusBar = "XY Data Generated by Yazaki <<erik.floresdelfin@mx.yazaki.com>>"
    'ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Then on the above code in some part I take each file in txt format, and I call a method which contains the url of the file that I want to open, the rest should be taking what tou need to copy and paste on the actual file, the final code I show is how to save the file asking to the user, sorry for the trash code but I think you caould manage taking what you need.

Comment: You could create a new tab in the final Excel File and called it Config, there you could save each element that you already processed, in that case in the beggining you will check if the file was already checked or not, the config tab could contain other thing as for example formulas to manage the last cell used, etc. that way you could use it cells as fields to save data that the code requires.